# Inserting text into field of attribute table in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, editing

I am populating an attribute table. After adding a field i have to populate the field with different texts in a sequential order like water, air, car, school etc. i have completed inserting water using the field calculator, how do i add the others.

Comment: Can you explain 'sequential order'?  As in, alphabetical? Or are there certain attributes you need to add based on other fields?

Answer (score 5):

Select the rows that you want to add the text in using the `Select by Attribute` from the selection drop down, then using a query to get only those rows.

Open the attribute table then use the Field Calculator to add the required text in the rows, enable editing before you use the field calculator as any changes made outside of an editing session are permanent, Repeat this for all the attributes.

If you want to change the text in the attribute table, select the text in the attribute table and press `control + f` or go to the attribute table drop down and select find and replace. In there select the replace tab and use it to change the text that you want, be careful that you use it on `Whole Field` and not the whole attribute table.

[image]

Comment: I think you have probably guessed what is being asked.  Your step to "choose `Show Selected Rows`" may or may not be helpful to visualize what is happening, but in any event it is unnecessary.

Comment: Agreed, just write a definition query based on the attribute you need and calculate the field.  Rinse repeat.

Comment: @StevenFerronato I love definition queries but I think the Select By Attributes way of doing this works fine.  Even though all the rows show up in the Attribute Table window, it is only the ones highlighted by the selection that get updated by the field calculation.

Comment: @PolyGeo true that step is probably not necessary but when I am entering data in rows, I don't like looking at empty rows, makes everything look a bit cluttered, just something I prefer doing.

Comment: I have already used the select by attribute to input the first set of text into the field, now i have to add the next sett of texts into the same field. i think writing the querry is the problem. i tried (60-120)="car" but didnt work, i am sure i did something wrong. Any suggestions

Comment: If you want to edit the field you should use the field calculator when you have enabled editing, (the changed made outside of an editing session are permanent).

Comment: ya i am in edit session, i have sellected the field, where do i locate show selected rows-

Comment: You want to add more data in the same field like after water you want to add air, car etc.?

Comment: ya, thats it. The alternative is to do it manually but this could be an orppotunity to learn the faster way too.

Comment: I don't think the field calculator will let you make changes on the field when it is not empty (already has "water" in it) the only way I can think of right now is using find and replace as i have shown in the edit above.

Answer (score 3):

1. Insert a column
2. Add your prefixes (air, car, water) by selecting the respective attributes using "select by attributes" and populate the fields using "field Calculator"
3. Insert another column and concatenate the two fields.

Hope this solves your problem.